# In istio, how are the principal names created?

Tags: istio

It’s not mentioned in the docs as to how a principal name is constructed. By principal I mean the name in the client certificate that istio sidecar creates and can be referenced in istio AuthorizationPolicy objects in the from directives of the spec.

By looking at the example yaml files used in the docs I was able to see that kubernetes ServiceAccount are part of the process. It appears to me that the ServiceAccount name is what’s used as part of the principal but that’s just a guess from looking at the examples. It’s not documented. So all I can infer is that a principal name is in the format:

```
cluster.local/ns/<namespace>/sa/<serviceaccountname>
```

Is there a guide for regular mere mortals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is very little about this even in envoy [documentation](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/rbac/v3/rbac.proto.html?highlight=principal#config-rbac-v3-principal) which matches
the istio source code comments found on [github](https://github.com/envoyproxy/go-control-plane/blob/master/envoy/config/rbac/v3/rbac.pb.go).

From search results [github](https://github.com/istio/istio/search?q=principals&type=code) it looks to me like you got template right. As it frequently appears in refactoring code files.

Comment: Thanks. Going to wait a little longer to see if anyone else has any ideas before accepting this as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Istio now documents the principal format under https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/#Source

> The peer identity is in the format of "<TRUST_DOMAIN>/ns/<NAMESPACE>/sa/<SERVICE_ACCOUNT>", for example, "cluster.local/ns/default/sa/productpage". This field requires mTLS enabled and is the same as the source.principal attribute.